# How can I use Google Cardboard in my portrait activity?

Tags: google-cardboard, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

My app has an activity use portrait mode(android:screenOrientation="portrait" in AndroidManifest.xml), for some reasons, I can't modify its screnOrientation value. Now I have to integrate the Google Cardbord feature to this activity, but the render looks weird as below picture shown, how can I fix this case? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: finally, I adust GLES20.glViewport(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height), my problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The system ignores screenOrientation if the activity is running in multi-window mode. Can you verify that you are not running in this mode?